# Spark Accumulators: Is the right accumulator sometimes many or always one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use a Spark accumulator to remove a group by query which has poor performance.

```
import org.apache.spark._
object CountPairsParam extends AccumulatorParam[Map[Int, Set[Int]]] {

  def zero(initialValue: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): Map[Int, Set[Int]] = {
    Map.empty[Int, Set[Int]]
  }

  def addInPlace(m1: Map[Int, Set[Int]], m2: Map[Int, Set[Int]]): Map[Int, Set[Int]] = {
    val keys = m1.keys ++ m2.keys
     keys.map((k: Int) => (k -> (m1.getOrElse(k, Set.empty[Int]) ++ m2.getOrElse(k, Set.empty[Int])))).toMap
  }
}
val accum = sc.accumulator(Map.empty[Int, Set[Int]])(CountPairsParam)
srch_destination_id_distinct.foreach(r => try{accum += Map(r(0).toString.toInt -> Set(r(1).toString.toInt))} catch {case ioe: NumberFormatException =>  Map.empty[Int, Set[Int]]})
```

In my accumulator I am assuming that m2 isn't going to always be a single item set created in my foreach loop, and that sometimes Spark will be using this method to add two different maps that have more then one key. But because of this my performance is low. Does the right Map always come into the accumulator with one item, set from my for each loop, or do I need to make this performance trade off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally avoid using `Accumulators` for anything but debugging because there's no guarantee, as far as I know, that each entry of the `RDD` will only be "added" into the `Accumulator` exactly once.

Maybe try something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.util.Try

val result = srch_destination_id_distinct.flatMap(r => 
  Try((r(0).toString.toInt, r(1).toString.toInt)).toOption
).aggregateByKey(HashSet.empty[Int])(
  (set, n) => set += n,
  (set1, set2) => set1 union set2
).mapValues(_.toSet).collectAsMap
```

The distinction between `seqOp` and `combOp` arguments of the `aggregate` method also allow us to avoid "wrapping" each element of the `RDD` in a `Map[Int, Set[Int]]` in the way you did with your approach.

Comment: You are almost correct. Spark doesn't guarantee that accumulator will be updated only once when it is used inside transformation. Accumulators used inside actions provide this guarantee. I doesn't affect the fact that aggregateByKey is a way better solution here :)